# Check SD Card after Saving Image (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

I have an intent that when complete, saves an image to /sdcard/Aperture. While the image does save, it does NOT show the image as soon as it is saved. What could be the problem? I tried using a scan broadcast in my On Activity Result but this causes a crash, and does not scan for the image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        MediaFragment content = (MediaFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(com.marlonjones.aperture.R.id.content_frame);
        if (content != null) content.reload();
        reloadNavDrawerAlbums();
    }
    if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
        // return from file upload
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
            }
        }
    }
}

 final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
public void camera(MenuItem menu) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasCameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");

        String newPicFile = "PH" + df.format(date)+".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);
        mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
        Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
    }
else{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");

        String newPicFile = "PH" + df.format(date) + ".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);
        mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
        Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);}
}
```

Comment: u can check exist this path

Comment: I added a check exist, but it still did not show the image in the gallery :/

Comment: Also tried this, which did NOT work: 'if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impression uses a MediaScannerConnection in some places I believe. It's a more modern version of using the scanner intent. It also tells you when scanning is complete and gives you the new URI (or null if the file was removed from the media database).

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { filePath }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
          Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
      }
});
```

You'd want to reload media and the albums after scanning is complete.

Comment: This did not work somehow :/ Here is the error: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Aperture/PH-35-52.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Code:  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[] { "/sdcard/Aperture" }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });

Comment: @VirusThePanda you might want to try passing the file URI rather than just the path. Like Uri.fromFile(file).toString()

Comment: Make sure the Aperture directory always exists too.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: @VirusThePanda oh I just noticed you were scanning the path to the directory, the MediaScanner only takes paths to individual files. You can pass multiple files in that array.